# JavaScript Promise Not Returning Correct Value

Tags: javascript

Hey I've been learning promises and can't understand why a's value in undefined in the code below.

```
a = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    resolve(5);
  }, 1000);
});

console.log(a);
```

Any explanations would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `console.log(a)` will print the *promise*. One second later that will be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `console.log` will execute immediately and will show the value of `a` which has a promise object assigned to it. So it will log `a` as an object.You will like to log the value once the `Promise` is `resolved`. Try logging inside the `then`

```js
a = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve(5);
  }, 1000);
});

a.then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```